# Prevent change Date and Copy Database By users

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

We are group of developers that create students software for free to help the schools to do their works with easy way

We are using VB.NET 2012 AND SQL COMPACT 3.5 as database for our software

We did some restrictions in our software and we are using some columns in the database as True or False for those restrictions like if you complete your student year, you cannot change the values of the degrees for the students

Recently the end users they start to copy the database before the date of the restrictions and they copy back the database and change the values

Is there and way to prevent users from copy the database back ?

We tried to use the clock of the user PC but that not a soulation as the use the still can change the date back

Hope i make my self clear for what we need

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: So you are looking for a way to flag if the database files themselves have been replaced?

Comment: Where is the database stored? Users would only have access to the database through the server. There should be no permissions to access the actual files.

Comment: 1. store database in server, not in user pc folder 
2. use just server clock for transaction date

Comment: Hursey, I'd be happy if there's a way that can mark the database if it has been replaced or not without using PC clock

Comment: Mary & user11982798 thx for your replay but as i mentioned above we are using SQL Compact Database and its stored in the same user PC not SQL server